# Safari vs Firefox: Strange UL "padding"

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari, html-lists

I have this HTML:

```
<article class="images">
  <ul class="cf">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

And this CSS:

```
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 .images ul {
  margin-left: -3%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.images li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.images li img {
  width: 17%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  float: left;
}
```

Still, in Safari the `ul` seems to have some kind of padding on the right.
In Firefox the `ul` is displayed correctly.

See it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/EdCXx/

Is there any way to fix that?

Edit: With Safari 6.0.2 on OS X 10.8.2 it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Seems fine to me. Safari 5.1.7 for Windows

Comment: @Diodeus I attached an image of the problem, see my edit.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element in the [Safari Developer tools](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html) to see what properties are being applied?

Comment: That's on the (ahem) RIGHT, not the left.

Comment: ha ha, no comment on this one ;-) @pwdst No I haven't because the problem can be reproduced isolated with a clear no-margig no-padding reset. I'll still take a look now.

Comment: You have a negative margin on the `ul`. Why? They look the same in Firefox and Safari (PC) to me.

Comment: To compensate the `margin-left` on every image, so that the images align nicely with the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the issue is that you're using negative `margin` and this is causing a problem (I don't have access to a Mac at the moment, so I can't verify).

Try changing your CSS to what's below. I also changed your `clearfix` to one I picked up a while ago that has had excellent cross-browser results.

http://jsfiddle.net/EdCXx/4/

CSS:

```
/* Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Clearfix */
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Images */
.images ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.images li {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
    height: 17%;
}
.images li img {
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

And tighten up your HTML (not necessary, but it's prettier):

```
<article class="images">
    <ul class="clear">
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x600" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Regarding the HTML: You're completely right, I've just written it that way because I thought it would make more what elements are there. Regarding the Clearfix: That's cool! Regarding the CSS: I get what you mean, but then how do I align the first image of each row with the left-edge of the `ul`? I think there is no other way.

Comment: How do you want it to look? You don't want even spacing around all of the images?

Comment: I do want even spacing around all of the images, the first image in each line needs to be the `margin-left` removed to line up with the `ul` and therefore with all other elements. Right now, it looks like the images are indented, but I want the `img` to line up on one line. See these two fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/EdCXx/2/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/EdCXx/3/

Comment: Can you use HTML5?  I usually use first-child pseudoelements to remove margins.

Comment: Or in your case, since there's rows of 5, I think you'd use :nth-child(5n+1).

Comment: See my updated answer. I just removed the padding from the `ul` and changed the `li` margin to `margin-right`.